# How to display first element of JSON in SwiftUI?

Tags: json, swift, api, swiftui

I am new to Swift and IOS development, and I am trying to display fetched JSON data onto a text label.

Essentially, my goal is to display **only the first object** of the following API call result onto a text label (see example further down)

JSON to decode:

```
[
   {
      "title":"Compound Hibernation",
      "content":"Those who glance about me\nwho cease to see inside the Sun\nwho cease to imagine its destabilized pre-quanta\ncannot know me\ncannot know my ethos as pumice\nas mingled apparition or flare\n\nmy perception through the prior sun that I ingest\nlike a blackened pre-existence\nor collected hawks through assignation\n\nthe Sun\nwith its dualisms\nwith its pre-biotic photons which waver\n\nperhaps\n9 suns before the Sun existed \nbefore the oceans seemed formed \nthere were molecular drafts\n\nakashic precursors \nfloating proto-ammonia\n\nI think of carbon \n&amp; wisps \n&amp; floodings\n\nof feral combat shelter \nwhere blank geometry accrues\n\nbefore separable biology was born\nbefore the contradictory ballast of de-existent protozoa\n\nbeing scorching photon by abstentia \nlike a pre-atomic sigil \ndestabilized as blizzard\n\na pre-cognitive rotation\na strange galvanics of the cosmos\n\n&amp; because of this galvanics\none reeks of invisible tremor\nwalking around in league with daunting helium affliction\n\nthus\nthe mirrors in my skin like haunted salamander fluid\nlike cells bereft with cooling centigrade rotation\n\ntherefore\nI know the abyss as volatile lunar transposition\nas sub-liminal mantis as climbing\nas splintering\n\ntherefore I am not\nan oily or blasphemous yogin\ncollapsing in default by sudden anger or water\n\nyet I am compound\nstruggling with scattered mental a-rhythmia\nwith partial psychic aphasia\nintensive\nillusive\naloof by interior compounding",
      "url":"https:\/\/www.poemist.com\/will-alexander\/compound-hibernation",
      "poet":{
         "name":"Will Alexander",
         "url":"https:\/\/www.poemist.com\/will-alexander"
      }
   },
   {
      "title":"His Lady Of The Sonnets Ix",
      "content":"Last night\u2013or was it in the golden morn\u2013\nOnce more I dreamed that I alone did fare\nForth into spirit-silences; and there\nI found you not; my star was set! Forlorn,\nI sought the kindred company of worn\nAnd stricken souls\u2013lost, sundered souls, who bear\nOld and avoided crosses with each care\nWoven together in their crowns of thorn.\n\nGods of the patient, vain endeavour, these\nClaimed me and called me fellow, comrade, friend,\nAnd bade me join in their brave litanies;\nBecause, though I had failed you, I dared bend\nBefore you without hope of one reward,\nSave that in loving you my soul still soared.",
      "url":"https:\/\/www.poemist.com\/robert-norwood\/his-lady-of-the-sonnets-ix",
      "poet":{
         "name":"Robert Norwood",
         "url":"https:\/\/www.poemist.com\/robert-norwood"
      }
   },
]
```

To do so, I've created the following Struct:

```
import Foundation

struct PoemData: Codable {
    public var title: String
    public var content: String
    public var poet: Poet

}

struct Poet: Codable {
    var name: String
}
```

And here is my attempt at an API Request and JSON Decoding:

```
 @State public var data = [PoemData(title: String("Poem Name"), content: String("Poem Content"), poet: Poet(name: "Poet Name"))]

    
    func getData() {
        let urlstring = "https://www.poemist.com/api/v1/randompoems"
        let url = URL(string: urlstring)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {data, response, error in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        let decodedData = try decoder.decode([PoemData].self, from: data)
                        self.data = decodedData
                        
                    } catch {
                        print (error)
                    }
                }

            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

My ultimate goal is to display the title and the content onto the following text labels:

```
Text(PoemData.title[0])
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .padding(.bottom, 40)
                            
                            Text("Poem Body" as String)
                                .font(.body)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .lineSpacing(6)
```

However, I'm unsure what to input within the Text labels. I have tried multiple variations such as `Text(PoemData.title[0])` however, none really worked out.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: `PoemData.title[0]` doesn't make sense, does it?  `PoemData` is the name of a model class.  It's not the name of an object as the result of instantiation.

Comment: Thanks for your input. What do you suggest instead?

Comment: `if let first = data.first { Text(first.title) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you wanted this

```
if let poem = data.first {
    Text(poem.title)
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .fontWeight(.heavy)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .padding(.bottom, 40)
    
    Text(poem.content)
        .font(.body)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .lineSpacing(6)

}
```